# two byte character or one byte character

Tags: c#, silverlight, character-encoding

How can I see if the input string is a two byte character or one byte character; and from which encoding system the character is coming from?

I am using C# and SilverLight; I assume I could find the encoding the computer is running and then the character? Any code snippet?

Thank you,
Rune

// Get a UTF-32 encoding by codepage.Encoding Encoding_12000_instance = Encoding.GetEncoding(12000);

// Get a UTF-32 encoding by name.Encoding Encoding_UTF32_instance = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-32");

Comment: Help us out. How are you getting the input? Depending on your starting point, the solutions vary.

Answer (score 2):

everything that is `string` in .net is in UTF-16. If you are getting input from other sources you need to get encoding name from it.

Comment: Yep.  If you want to see if it's Basic Latin, just check the character range.